# Messages shows wrong informations in the recent chats list

Tags: macos, messages, ichat

For some contacts the preview in the recent chats list shows wrong informations. When I click on the preview, I get a totally different chat in the detail view.

*Running Mountain Lion 10.8.2*

Any ideas?

[image: Messages Screenshot]

Comment: im gonna tell you bluntly, Messenger app is super buggy, and does not sync well...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. Messages will work when it works, and fail when it fails. Unfortunately there isn't a solid fix from Apple (yet).